# Given target MethodInfo, create new hooked MethodInfo that first calls Action then the target

Tags: c#, hook

Is it possible to, given a `MethodInfo`, programatically create a new `MethodInfo` that first calls some pre-hook and then the original `MethodInfo`, returning whatever the original `MethodInfo` return (which could be void)?

Something like:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = // Get arbitrary MethodInfo
Action PreHook = () => Console.WriteLine("PreHook");
MethodInfo hookedMethodInfo = // Create new MethodInfo that first calls PreHook, then calls methodInfo, and finally returns the return value of methodInfo if it has one
```

Comment: Sure, but I suggest using an AOP (aspect-oriented programming) framework, like PostSharp, instead of trying to do it yourself. AOP is really good at handling cross-cutting concerns, like logging method entry/exit.

Comment: I'm open to using libraries if such exists, but PostSharp is a no go as it is not free (as in beer). The library would also need to use a permissive license. I found Ryder which seems to do most of the work, but, if I understand thing correctly, I still need to create either modified MethodInfos of Deletgates.

I'm also not interested in using attributes, it need to be done  programmatically at runtime.

Comment: The way PostSharp works is that it rewrites the assembly to modify the method itself to include the pre- and post-method code you've provided. This means that you can call the original method rather than invoking from a `MethodInfo` or a delegate instance. I don't know about Ryder.

Comment: It's easy enough to wrap a delegate in one that does something before or after the original. Have you tried that? What's your actual use case? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @madreflection I want to, at runtime, given a some `Type`, pre-hook some of its methods. By pre-hooking I mean that some by me provided `Action` should be run before the pre-hooked method every time it is called. I do not wish to interrupt or change the result of the original method, only run my `Action` in addition. I do not wish to use any library that costs money or uses a non-permissive license.

Comment: Can you substitute the class with one of your own? If so, consider the Decorator pattern.

Comment: @madreflection No. My code runs some other code. The other code can not be rewritten. My code wants to pre-hook methods from the other code. These methods to pre-hook are found by reflection.

Comment: I didn't say to rewrite the other code. I was talking about writing an object that looks like the other one and does the hook calls before calling the other one. It depends on the other code, of course... if it implements an interface, for example, you implement that interface and use your object where you were using the other before (much easier to do if it's dependency-injected!). Then give your object a reference to the other one and call its methods as part of your implementation.

Comment: I'm not able to replace the types used by the other code, there are no interface to implement, no dependency injection, it is pretty much black box but I can access the assemblies/classes/methods via reflection. I understand you are trying to help, but what I really want to know is if it is possible to do what I asked in the original question. In this question I'm not looking for alternative approaches.

Comment: What will you use `hookedMethodInfo` for once you have it working?